# Is it correct to say A, B or neither

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is this following statement correct?

The student must be able to determine  whether a sequence is arithmetic,geometric , or neither .

I mean is this a correct usage of “neither”?
If not, what would be the correct wording ?

Comment: ...arithmetic, geometry, or neither. I think it is OK.

Comment: Why do you think that it might not be correct?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be correct. Neither, being not either, would be a good way of saying not either of the two listed here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of mutually exclusive possibilities (in general, an arithmetic sequence is not a geometric sequence) so the structure lists them all correctly as: A, B, or [(NOT A) AND (NOT B)]. Some people who answer may feel the last comma is not needed.

Comment: So can I replace [ (NOT A) and (NOT B) ] with neither?

Comment: yes that is how I understand "neither" in this sentence.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of mistakes

- it's whether rather than wether
- you should use the present tense, that is 'is' rather than 'was'
- and you have a hanging adjective - saying 'a sequence is arithmetic or geometric' by itself isn't grammatically correct.

However, the use of neither is fine.

Comment: Considering the third point , I felt it wasn’t that correct . Would it be better if I said : a sequence is an algebraic one , a geometric one or neither  ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "hanging adjectives". At least, not in this sentence.